# My 8 month old unsexed leopard gecko hasn't been eating properly for 2 weeks what should i do?

Tags: eating, leopard-geckos

It has only eaten once in this time when it ate 10 mealworms and has defecated twice. Its faeces are about half the normal size. Its behaviour is normal apart from it has started scratching at night for about an hour at a time every other night. Any advice is welcome.
Thankyou